# Google Maps API- why does my code only display 1 marker and not 2?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <style type="text/css">
          html { height: 100% }
          body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
          #map-canvas { height: 100% }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript"
          src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API-KEY&sensor=false">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        /* Northborough coordinates  */
        function initialize() {
            var mayOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.714353, -74.005973),
                zoom: 5,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                mapOptions);

            // First Marker
            var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.713400, -74.007908),
            map: map
            });

            // Marker1 info window
            var infowindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: 'Drew Pickles'
            });

            // Click event to Marker1
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function() {
            infowindow1.open(map, marker1);
            }); 

            // Second Marker
            var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.712050, -74.004647),
            map: map });

            // Marker2 info window
            var infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: 'Teemo' 
                });

            // Click event to Marker2
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function() {
            infowindow2.open(map, marker2);
            });

            }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

         </script>
         </head>
         <body>
              <div id="map-canvas"> </div> 
         </body>
         </html>
```

The above code is supposed to display 2 markers with their associated info windows. When I run it nothing shows. The map isn't rendering at all. I removed my API key for obvious reasons when posting this on here.

One marker displays but not the other. Why is that?

Comment: Better to check the browser console (by pressing F12) so you can fix those error by yourself.  Hope you understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your `initialize()` function.

It should be

```
var mapOptions = {
```

not:

```
var mayOptions = {
```

---

Use the `console` of your browser when tracking errors in Javascript. It should give you something similar to:

```
▶ Uncaught ReferenceError: mapOptions is not defined       (some-file-name):123
```

Click on file-name/line-number to get to point of origin for error.

Comment: @user3223207: Both markers should be there. You have, however, to zoom in as they are rather close to each other.